# how to implement a character animation in my android app?

Tags: android, animation

I want to implement the character animation used in the "Wake me up Asuna" app, for a character in my app and I do not know where to start, or where to look or investigate.

Comment: Hello, you should improve the quality of your question. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, there modify it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The framework that i was locking for is "Live2D".